# How to read this x86 assembly "for" loop

Tags: for-loop, assembly

```
CheckIfStop:
   cmp eax, 5
   jnl End
```

Translation in the book says "a conditional jump is taken if eax is not less than (is greater than or equal to) the value of 5."

Why is can't it be read (opposite) as "...if 5 is not less than (is greater than or equal to) the value of `eax`? I'm not seeing how to read the connection between `jnl` and the values `eax` and 5.

Reference states, `cmp` is Op1-Op2.

Thanks!

Comment: The conditional `jnl` checks the *Overflow Flag* (`OF`) and the *Sign Flag* (`SF`)  (bits `11` and `7` of the flags, respectively) [**TutorialsPoint Assembly Tutorial**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_conditions.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Most of instructions are not symmetric: `or eax, ebx` reads both registers but only set `eax`.
So it's not surprising that the same is true for `cmp`: the first operand is the one compared with the second and the subject of the conditional check made by the `jcc` family of instruction.

`cmp eax, 5`  reads *Compare EAX with 5* and `jnl End` reads *If it is not less then jump to End*.

The tricks of considering the first source of `cmp` as the subject works well but I wouldn't be surprise if it sometimes fails.
Remember that `cmp` is just a `sub` that throw away the result but still set the flags, later tested with a `jcc` instruction.

Subtraction is not commutative so `cmp eax, ebx` and `cmp ebx, eax` have two different semantic: both compares EAX and EBX but the first is from the perspective of EAX (so a `ja` would test EAX > EBX) and the latter from the perspective of EBX (so a `ja` would test EBX > EAX).

Answer (score 0):

The description for `CMP` is:

> Compares the first source operand with the second source operand and sets the status flags in the EFLAGS register
>   according to the results. The comparison is performed by subtracting the second operand from the first operand
>   and then setting the status flags in the same manner as the SUB instruction.

So the flags are set based on `eax-5` in your case.

And `JNL` means *"Jump if SF==OF"* (where `SF` is the sign flag, and `OF` is the overflow flag).

---

How can we end up with `SF`==`OF`? Well, `SF` is pretty obvious, it will be set if the result of the subtraction is negative, and clear otherwise.

`OF` will be set in either of these cases for subtractions:

- Positive Op1 - Negative Op2 = Negative Result
- Negative Op1 - Positive Op2 = Positive Result

So the only case where we can get `SF`=1 and `OF`=1 is when a positive Op1 and a negative Op2 yielded a negative result. Obviously 5 isn't negative, so this wouldn't fit your proposed description.

---

Let's look at `SF`=0 and `OF`=0. This can happen in the following cases:

- Positive Op1 - Positive Op2 = Positive Result
- Positive Op1 - Negative Op2 = Positive Result
- Negative Op1 - Negative Op2 = Positive Result

The only one of these where Op2=5 would fit in is the first. But that one also requires a positive Op1 and a positive result, which will only happen if Op1 is greater than or equal to Op2, i.e. if 5 is less than or equal to Op1.